# how to apply a rule involving a hundred variables in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an expression which involves x1,x2,...,x100, I also have a list `lst` with 100 elements, how to apply the rule to this expression to achieve something like the following:

```
exp/.{x1->lst[[1]],x2->lst[[2]],...,x100->lst[[100]]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 exp /.  Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]] -> lst[[i]], {i, 1, 100}]
```

So you don't need to write X1,X2, ... X100

Comment: For very long replacement lists that are applied to complex formulas I recommend using `Dispatch`: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html.

Comment: @Timo You are right, Dispatch optimizes a lot! Thanks for remembering that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Thread` to apply the rules to each pair of expressions:

```
Thread[{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler and more convenient to solve such tasks using indexed variables instead of generation of a list of different `Symbol`s. In this way:

```
listOfRules = Array[f@# :> list[[#]] &, {100}];
Short@%

=> {f[1]:>list[[1]],f[2]:>list[[2]],f[3]:>list[[3]],f[4]:>list[[4]],
<<92>>,f[97]:>list[[97]],f[98]:>list[[98]],f[99]:>list[[99]],f[100]:>list[[100]]}
```

If you plan to make such replacement many times, it is worth to `Dispatch` large list of rules:

```
listOfRules = Dispatch@listOfRules;
```

The replacement can be made as usual:

```
expr /. listOfRules
```