# How do I save multiple variables with an iterated name in Mathematica?

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica, iteration

I want to create multiple variables with iterated names in Mathematica, something like this:

```
Do["f" <> ToString[i] = i*2, {i, 1, 20}]
```

where I get f1=2, f2=4, f3=6, ... and so on.

I the error:

> Set::write: Tag StringJoin in f<>1 is Protected. >>

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: there was a question. Let me search

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743121/how-to-apply-a-rule-involving-a-hundred-variables-in-mathematica/4743301#4743301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you need to evaluate the `"f" <> ToString[i]` expression before `Set` (`=`) sees it, or you attempt to assign to an object with head `StringJoin`, just as the error message tries to tell you.  Further, you cannot make an assignment to a string, so you need to convert it to a Symbol, using (surprise) `Symbol`.  One method is to use `Evaluate`:

```
Do[Evaluate[Symbol["f" <> ToString[i]]] = i*2, {i, 1, 20}]

{f1, f2, f17}
```

> {2, 4, 34}

This however is not usually a good course of action with *Mathematica*.  For example, if any of these symbols already exist and have a value assigned the operation will fail.  One *can* get around this with more effort as seen in the answers to [How to Block Symbols without evaluating them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6234701/618728) (or more specifically in [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/784/121)) but again, it is not usually a good course of action.

The normal method is to use [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) as PrinceBilliard shows.

Please see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121), its answers, and the four related questions linked in the comment below it for more on this topic in general.

Answer (score 2):

`Do[f[i] = i^2, {i,1,20}]`

Iterated variable names work like f[i]. You can also declare iterated function names, such as `f[2][x_] := ...`

Comment: Dear PrinceBilliard, if Mathematica is your favorite thing ever, is there a reason we haven't seen you over at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?